# Como retornar o array de anos usando react-select

Tags: javascript, react, react-select

Estou usando o `react-select` para fazer um select no projeto React.
Eu preciso retornar os últimos 5 anos.
E depois popular o `options={}` do Select.
Só que ele tá pegando apenas o ultimo ano, no caso o 2020, mas não tá trazendo a lista inteira, que seria: 2020,2019,2018,2017,2016

```
  const getOptions = () => {
    const years = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      years.push(new Date().getFullYear() - i);
    }

    for (let valor of years) {
      console.log(valor);
      const anos = [
        {
          value: valor,
          label: valor
        }
      ];

      console.log("years", years);
      console.log("anos", anos);
      return anos;
    }
  };
```

Select:

```
 <Select
        placeholder="Ano"
        value={props.values.ano}
        onChange={selectedOption => {
          handleChange("ano")(selectedOption);
        }}
        isSearchable={true}
        options={getOptions()}
        styles={customStyles}
        name="ano"
        isLoading={false}
        loadingMessage={() => "Carregando os ano"}
        noOptionsMessage={() => "Não tem ano"}
      />
```

Ele carrega apenas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você se confundiu

como seu código atribui um valor, ao inves de incrementar o array, é natural que aconteça isso

repare:

```
for (let valor of years) {
  const anos = [
    {
     value: valor,
     label: valor
    }
  ];    
  return anos;
 }
```

o correto seria você incrementar com `push` resultando num codigo assim:

```
anos.push({
  value: valor,
  label: valor
 })
```

defina `let anos` antes do `for`, e implemente o `push` em anos, dentro do for de `years`.

assim como a `const years` foi definido antes do for.

```
const years = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  years.push(new Date().getFullYear() - i);
}
```

o retorno da função getOptions deve ficar fora do for assim terminando as atribuições e depois retornando o array.

```
 let anos = [];
 for (let valor of years) {
  anos.push({
     value: valor,
     label: valor
    })  
 }
 return anos;
```

Uma dica use `let` ao inves de `const.` A **const** se refere a constante ou seja não muda, mas **let** define uma variavel dentro de um `escopo` que pode ser mudada durante a execussão do mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode optar por uma solução um pouco mais declarativa, sem a necessidade de usar uma solução imperativa. Não há nada de errado com o `for`, mas ele foge um pouco dos padrões "imutáveis" que o React prega.

Então, você pode fazer também algo como:

```js
function getOptions(ammount = 5) {
  return Array.from({ length: ammount })
    .map((_, index) => new Date().getFullYear() - index);
}

console.log(getOptions());
```

Basicamente, estamos criando uma lista com 5 elementos e mapeando cada elemento desse array para um ano em específico. Para isso, fazemos uma subtração do ano atual menos o índice do elemento, então, teremos:

- Primeira iteração, índice zero: `2020 - 0` -> `2020`;
- Segunda iteração, índice um: `2020 - 1` -> `2019`;
- Terceira iteração, índice dois: `2020 - 2` -> `2018`;
- Quarta iteração, índice três: `2020 - 1` -> `2017`;
- Quinta iteração, índice quatro: `2020 - 4` -> `2016`.

Comment: Gostei da forma que você fez, principalmente a explicação de imperativo e declarativo.